# Why is the output going into infinity

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, binary-search-tree, preorder

This is the code i am using to add in the BST.And this is the preorder function.Why is it going into infinity?I am taking the input from the user about the element to add.But the output goes into infinity.

```
    void add(){
      struct node* temp=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
      struct node* current=root;
      printf("\nEnter the data:\n");
      scanf("%d",&temp->data);
      while(current->left!=NULL && current->right!=NULL){
            parent=current;
        if(temp->data > parent->data){
            current=current->right;
        }
        else{
            current=current->left;
        }

      }
      if(temp->data > parent->data){
            parent->right=temp;
            parent->left=NULL;
        }
        else{
            parent->left=temp;
            parent->right=temp;
        }
    }

    void preorder(struct node* node)
    {
         if (node == NULL)
              return;

         /* first print data of node */
         printf("%d ", node->data);

         /* then recur on left subtree */
         preorder(node->left);

         /* now recur on right subtree */
         preorder(node->right);
    }
```

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger to step through your program, statement by statement. For these kinds of problems a quick debugging session should be able to help figure out the problem quickly.

Comment: @Abhiraj Kale The function add has undefined behavior because initially root can be equal to NULL.

Comment: At one point in the `add` function, it is setting `parent->left` and `parent->right` to point to the same node. That doesn't look right.

Comment: `temp->left` and `temp->right` are never initialized to `NULL`, so they will contain invalid pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function add has undefined behavior.

For starters root initially can be equal to NULL. So you may not use this approach

```
  struct node* current=root;
  //...
  while(current->left!=NULL && current->right!=NULL){
```

because there is an attempt to access memory using a null-pointer.

Secondly this loop

```
  while(current->left!=NULL && current->right!=NULL){
        parent=current;
```

does not process a node that contains only one child node not equal to NULL.

Also you are not setting to NULL data members left and right of the created node temp.

And there is a typo in these statements

```
        parent->left=temp;
        parent->right=temp;
```

So the function definition is invalid.

And the function should do only one thing: append a node to the tree. It should not prompt the user to enter some data.

Take into account that it is a bad idea to use a global variable for the root node.

Nevertheless here is a demonstrative program that uses your approach. I call this approach Java-approach (in C the function add can be written much simpler)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left, *right;
};

struct node *root;

_Bool add( int data )
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    _Bool success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data  = data;
        new_node->left  = NULL;
        new_node->right = NULL;

        if ( root == NULL )
        {
            root = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            for ( struct node *current = root; ; )
            {
                struct node *parent = current;

                if ( data < current->data )
                {
                    current = current->left;
                    if ( current == NULL )
                    {
                        parent->left = new_node;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    current = current->right;
                    if ( current == NULL )
                    {
                        parent->right = new_node;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}

void preorder( const struct node *node )
{
    if ( node != NULL )
    {
        printf( "%d ", node->data );
        preorder( node->left );
        preorder( node->right );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) add( rand() % N );

    preorder( root );

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
4 0 3 2 1 0 1 2 5 8
```

And below there is a demonstrative program that shows how the function add can be written using the C approach. In the program the global variable root is removed and substituted for a local variable root.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left, *right;
};

_Bool add( struct node **root, int data )
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    _Bool success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data  = data;
        new_node->left  = NULL;
        new_node->right = NULL;

        while ( *root != NULL )
        {
            if ( data < ( *root )->data ) root = &( *root )->left;
            else root = &( *root )->right;
        }

        *root = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

void preorder( const struct node *node )
{
    if ( node != NULL )
    {
        printf( "%d ", node->data );
        preorder( node->left );
        preorder( node->right );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct node *root = NULL;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) add( &root, rand() % N );

    preorder( root );

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Now investigate and compare the two implementations of the function add.

Comment: thanks, but why is it not a good idea to declare variables globally ? I am a beginner

Comment: @AbhirajKale Because in this case you can not have for example two binary trees.

Answer (score -1):

You have to rewrite your add method in this way,

```
void add()
    {
        int data;
        printf("\nEnter the data:\n");
        scanf("%d",data);
        root = insert_rec(root, data);
    }
struct node* insert_rec(struct node* current, int data)
    {


        if(current == NULL)
        {
            struct node* temp=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->data = data;
            current = temp;
            return current;
        }
        else
        {
            if(current->data > data)
            {
                current->left = insert_rec(current->left, data);
            }
            else
            {
                current->right = insert_rec(current->right, data);
            }
        }
        return current;
    }
```

This is recursive way of BST insertion.
Hope this might helps:)

Comment: You forgot to set `temp->left` and `temp->right` to `NULL`.